# Convert Apache to Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

I'd like to convert that rewrite code of Apache to Nginx.

Can you help me?

The code of application have 2 files: .htaccess

In the main folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    <Files ~ "\.(env|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

In the sub folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to know how to generate the code to put on rewrite nginx to make the laravel program work.

Comment: Maybe this site can help you. https://winginx.com/en/htaccess